# Is Qt's connect call itself thread safe?

Tags: c++, qt

I know you can connect signal slot that lives in different thread (has different thread affinity.)
But is the connect call it self thread safe?

Say if I want to call:

```
connect(mainObject,SIGNAL(...),this,SLOT());
```

in two different thread?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the documentation here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect
at the end there is the note

> Note: This function is thread-safe.